# wp_schedule_event seems to be being added twice

Tags: plugin-development

I want to add to wp_schedule_event when the plugin is activated, the code I need does run on the hour, but seems to run twice and I can't work out why, I expect I am doing something incorrect with the way I am calling this.

This is what I have

plugin.php file

```
namespace GrantName {
  if ( ! defined('ABSPATH' ) ){
    die();
  }
  class Plugin {
    private static $instance = null;
    private static $plugin_dir;  

    private function __construct(){
      $autoloader_path = self::getPluginFilePath("/autoloader.php");
      require_once($autoloader_path);
      Autoloader::register();

      new AdminSupport();
      $adminClass = new AdminSupport(); 

      // These are the de/activation hooks.
      register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($adminClass, 'my_activation'));
      register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array($adminClass,'my_deactivation' ));

    }
```

AdminSupport.php

```
namespace GrantName;
class AdminSupport {

  public function onInitialize(){
    add_action('my_hourly_event', array($this, 'do_this_hourly' ));
  }

  public function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event' );
  }

  public function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
    $this->assessplugins();
  }

  public function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'my_hourly_event' );
  }

  public function assessplugins(){
    //Does some things
  }
};
```

It seems that the scheduled tasks run twice, one after the other.  I installed a plugin to show the tasks and I see that the job has two actions (`do_this_hourly()` twice).

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I think the issue is that `init` is called multiple times, so my hooks are added more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you know what's going on - here's a way to avoid running the activation method more than once:

```
class AdminSupport {
    protected static $activated = false;

    public function onInitialize(){
        add_action('my_hourly_event', array($this, 'do_this_hourly' ));
    }

    public function my_activation() {
        if ( self::$activated ) {
            return;
        }

        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event' );
        self::$activated = true;
    }

    public function do_this_hourly() {
        // do something every hour
        $this->assessplugins();
    }

    public function my_deactivation() {
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'my_hourly_event' );
    }

    public function assessplugins(){
        //Does some things
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually add the self::$activated = true; part into the onInitialize function, like this: if ( !self::$activated ) { //do the things that should happen once;      self::$activated = true;} - thanks for the help